# How to disable migration in Entity Framework 4.3.1?

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-4.3

Is there any way to disable migration in Entity Framework 4.3.1? I removed the migrations folder from the project and the generated tables in my database, but it doesn't work! How can you remove the migration?

Comment: What do you mean by *it not works*?

Comment: I mean when I delete these file and table, I ecpect to migration disabled, but it is enable yet. when I run the project it occurs an error about migration

Comment: Try to add `Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null)` to startup of your application.

Comment: It works. Thank you. But now, how can I create database with ef?

Comment: For EF6 see [How can I disable migration in Entity Framework 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18667172)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you don't want to use migrations but in the same time you want EF to create database for you, you just need to set correct database initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourContentType>());
```

Comment: new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourContentType>()

Comment: What class/file does this actually go in?

Comment: @jep, the entry point for your application. E.g. `global.asax.cs` or `Program.Main`.

Comment: This does not work in EF6. MSFT turned it off because of conflicts between the migration and the intitializers. See http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1689

Comment: How to make it ALWAYS rebuild from scratch even if there was no changes? I tried many things to do so.

Comment: In aspnet.core 2.0 I get the error: 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a defininition for 'SetInitializer'.

Answer (score 35):

Deleting the `Migrations` folder has worked for me. I don't get any errors, it puts me back to where I started.

Comment: The Migrations folder where? I'm EF6 code-first and don't seem to have one anywhere. I certainly didn't make one.

Answer (score 4):

The way that I got around this was to make sure that I turned off Automatic Migrations in my code:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

and then I deleted the _MigrationHistory table from the database (this is usually created as a system table if you can't find it)

Comment: Down vote for being so vague. Where exactly in your code did you include that command?

Comment: hmmm... good question JBeckton.  it's been a while since I've looked at that code, and I don't think that I still have access to it anywhere.  I remember that it was in the Entity Framework setup section of my code.

Not very helpful, I know, so my apologies on that.

Comment: `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` property is located in /Migrations/Configuration.cs