# Reset Entity-Framework Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I've mucked up my migrations, I used `IgnoreChanges` on the initial migration, but now I want to delete all my migrations and start with an initial migration with all of the logic.

When I delete the migrations in the folder and try and `Add-Migration` it doesn't generate a full file (it's empty - because I haven't made any changes since my last, but now deleted, migration).

Is there any *Disable-Migrations* command, so I can rerun `Enable-Migrations`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703810/how-to-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-4-3-1

Comment: One important note if you have multiple connectionstrings: specify which one to use when you reset the migrations, otherwise it will try to apply to both which may cause issues when there are discrepancies.

Comment: Note: If you hadn't deleted your migrations (you do use version control right?), you could have update your db -to you first migration then deleted the mitigation and created new migrations from that point. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23793384/309634

Answer (score 516, accepted):

You need to :

1. Delete the state: Delete the migrations folder in your project; And
2. Delete the `__MigrationHistory` table in your database (may be under system tables); Then
3. Run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

   ```
   Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force
   ```

   Use with or without `-EnableAutomaticMigrations`
4. And finally, you can run:

   ```
   Add-Migration Initial
   ```

Comment: Weird.  I followed these instructions to the letter, but when I go to do "Enable-Migrations ..." it tells me that my Configuration.cs file already exists... (I look on the disk before I execute this command, the file does not exist!)

Comment: ^^ Figured it out -- it was a TFS error -- if you're using TFS you need to perform a check-in before running the "Enable-Migrations ..." command. :D

Comment: If you're not using version control, save your Seed values before you delete!

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan if you're not using version control, you deserve to lose your work. :-)

Comment: @Tood.  +1 to that.  Saved me a lot of time.  Now if only the EF team could incorporate all that into a Reset-Migrations command.  Maybe EF 6...

Comment: @Todd, how do you get it to treat that new migration as already having been applied, i.e. to insert it into the __MigrationsHistory table without running it? I get errors when I start my application (using update to latest initializer) or run Update-Database unless I use Greg Gum's suggestion below to comment out the Up method.

Comment: For an existing database, you need to comment out the content of the "Up" function.  Otherwise you'll get an error when you run "Update-Database", it would complain that the table already exists

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I still get the same error after applying the steps mentioned above. On the other hand, the comment seems to be very useful: "For an existing database, you need to comment out the content of the "Up" function. Otherwise you'll get an error when you run "Update-Database", it would complain that the table already exists". I tried it and the error has gone, but my database was not updated. Any idea pls?

Comment: Thanks @Todd : What about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547951/update-existing-database-with-entity-framework-code-first-in-mvc

Comment: Also you can try to change database name in the connection string. Once I had tried everything to reset migrations even deleting database after all it's ok when changing database name.

Comment: Is it really safe to remove the *__MIgrationsHistory* table? EF supports multiple context from version 6, so removing the table isn't equivalent to removing the removing the rows corresponding to the context that we regard. Or is it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - you raise a potentially valid point, but one that may be too rare. Multiple contexts are rare for me. If I do, the additional ones are generally read-only. This table is stored on the Database: it would be also a rare design to have multiple contexts on the same database. Therefore I assume that having multiple Contexts on the same Database with Migrations would be both rare, and with no clear design reasons coming to mind. For this reason, I don't see a need to update my post, and your comment of caution should suffice.

Comment: That might be my ignorance talking, so it's great that you took time to address it. In my projects I usually have at least two contexts. One that is **the one** and the other for security management (the one responsible for the tables in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34382196/1525840) image). But I agree with you that it's uncommon to have multiple contexts by design for the main logic. Not sure what the advantage of it would be, even...

Comment: I can't delete the MigrationsHistory table, everytime it opens a window saying it can't be deleted beacuse it is being edited(but it isn't) and then it opens the editor window.

Comment: @Baxtex That sounds like a problem with SQL Management Studio (SSMS). You could try and write a direct `Drop Table __MigrationsHistory` statement. Also check you have the latest SSMS. Also check you have rights to make DDL changes - Create/Drop Table rights. Finally, also try turning your computer off and on.

Comment: I'm using .NET Web API w/ Entity Framework Code First From Database just to generate our models and controllers. I was following a pretty unrelated tutorial and typed Enable-Migrations in nuget console for our existing database connection. I didn't code further from here, and I want to undo this - so I deleted the Migrations folder which didnt exist prior. Will this suffice in my case, or do I need to do all the steps you listed? My point is - I don't know if my migrations are mucked up now or not. Disable-Migrations doesn't work, and I cant find a `_MigrationHistory` table in the db...

Comment: @KyleVassella The table will only exist if you apply updates. Enabling migrations creates the initial migration in your project. I believe the `_MigrationHistory` table only appears on the database in your default connection string when you run `Update-Database` (I think that's the correct command).

Comment: I get this message: `Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations.`

Answer (score 201):

The Issue: You have mucked up your migrations and you would like to reset it without deleting your existing tables.

The Problem: You can't reset migrations with existing tables in the database as EF wants to create the tables from scratch.

What to do:

1. Delete existing migrations from Migrations_History table.
2. Delete existing migrations from the Migrations Folder.
3. Run add-migration Reset.  This will create a migration in your Migration folder that includes creating the tables (but it will not run it so it will not error out.)
4. You now need to create the initial row in the MigrationHistory table so EF has a snapshot of the current state. EF will do this if you apply a migration.  However, you can't apply the migration that you just made as the tables already exist in your database.  So go into the Migration and comment out all the code inside the "Up" method.
5. Now run update-database.  It will apply the Migration (while not actually changing the database) and create a snapshot row in MigrationHistory.

You have now reset your migrations and may continue with normal migrations.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. The accepted answer doesn't seem to address the issue of what happens when you run Update-Database or run your application (depending on what kind of initializer you're using). It will try to run the migration and try to make changes that already exist. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It's also the answer that's more flexible. In my case there were some changes that I needed applied and some others not. I could just keep the useful stuff in my Up().

Comment: @GregGum: What about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547951/update-existing-database-with-entity-framework-code-first-in-mvc

Comment: @H.Johnson, I am not sure what you are asking me :)

Comment: @GregGum: Thanks for reply. Could you please have a look at this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570916/defining-multiple-foreign-key-for-the-same-table-in-entity-framweork-code-first

Comment: @H.Johnson, I have looked at it. Did you have a question about it?

Comment: @GregGum: I have received an answer for it. Anyway, thanks a lot for yıur kind help :)

Comment: Is this still the best way to get rid of multiple migrations files? I'm worried about the migration snapshot, isn't it a problem that the snapshot in the database will have an incorrect Up() method?

Comment: The first steps are to delete all old migrations, so it won't be a problem.

Comment: After I have done this, how do I update my production website to use the new migration chain?

Comment: One thing to be aware of, from EF 6.0 the _MigrationsHistory table contains migrations for multiple DBContexts. Deleting it can cause issues, you should only delete the rows where ContextKey = your migration name. Also after 2 above I had to enable-migrations again

Comment: Essentially the same answer, with an expanded example (with screenshots): https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate

Comment: Result: There is already an object named 'MyView' in the database. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you do step 4 above?

Comment: @GregGum How do i sync my customer database schema with my new reset migrations and proceed going forward. What if they are 2 schema changes behind the snapshot of the reset?

Comment: This is BY FAR the best approach for .net core, as -IgnoreChanges has been removed, but you should always keep the code for initial creation (UP) method available if needed.

Comment: the issue and the problem are synonyms

Comment: Missing last step: un-comment those UP routines.  They will be needed for the next environment that you deploy to (where the tables don't exist). And they won't bother anything in the current environment because the history table knows they have already been applied.

Comment: Note that for me, i also needed to delete the snapshot file (it is re-created when adding the migration). Without deleting the snapshot, the new migration was empty as it assumed that nothing changed.

Answer (score 32):

In Entity Framework Core.

1. Remove all files from the migrations folder.
2. Type in console

   ```
   dotnet ef database drop -f -v
   dotnet ef migrations add Initial
   dotnet ef database update
   ```
3. (Or for Package Manager Console)

   ```
   Drop-Database -Force -Verbose
   Add-Migration Initial
   Update-Database
   ```

UPD: Do that only if you don't care about your current persisted data. If you do, [use Greg Gum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451879/7313872)

Comment: Don't do this if you want to preserve your existing data (if you only want to "reset migrations")

Comment: Be careful with this. The question asked for resetting the migrations, not to wipe the db data clean.

Comment: Second the above. I ran the first command thinking it might drop the tables, it dropped the entire database!

Comment: Yes, it's pretty unexpected behavior when you write the command to console "Drop-Database" it suddenly drops the database.

Comment: @LiamKernighan Sure, that one is self-explanatory enough. The one I used from your answer, `dotnet ef database drop`, I would argue is slightly less clear cut. Regardless, your warning message at the bottom is insufficiently clear - you say "if you don't care about your current persisted data", it's far more than that. If we're talking about a database shared with other apps, the result of this operation can be quite bad.

Answer (score 30):

How about

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: $InitialDatabase
```

in Package Manager Console? It should reset all updates to its very early state.

Reference link: [Code First Migrations - Migrating to a Specific Version (Including Downgrade)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621#specific)

Comment: I think my main frustration was no longer trusting migrations to accurately maintain state. And as a result wanting to start from scratch.

Comment: @Todd, I stumbled along and it wasn't always clear if I should delete the migration files to start all over. Now it is working the following: 1. revert back to initial using the command "Update-Database –TargetMigration: $InitialDatabase". 2. Remove all migration files (named using yyyyMMddHHmmssx_Name.cs or .vb) 3. Refresh the update by using 'add-Migration -Name some_name'. 4. Issue the update to affect your database using 'update-Database'. Hope it works for you.

Comment: In my case, the suggested command in this answer resulted in SQL errors.

Comment: what should it mean "InitialDatabase"? will it delete the tables or columns already created in the DB?

Answer (score 19):

To fix this, You need to:

1. Delete all *.cs files in the Migrations Folder.
2. Delete the _MigrationHistory Table in the Database
3. Run `Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force`
4. Run `Add-Migration Reset`

Then, in the `public partial class Reset : DbMigration` class, you need to comment all of the existing and current Tables:

```
public override void Up()
{
// CreateTable(
// "dbo.<EXISTING TABLE NAME IN DATABASE>
// ...
// }
...
}
```

**If you miss this bit all will fail and you have to start again!**

5. Now Run `Update-Database -verbose`

This should be successful if you have done the above correctly, and now you can carry on as normal.

Comment: Instead of commenting out everything, you also can just write "return;" in the first line of method Up().

Answer (score 10):

Considering this still shows up when we search for EF in .NET Core, I'll post my answer here (Since it has haunted me a lot). Note that there are some subtleties with the EF 6 .NET version (No initial command, and you will need to delete "Snapshot" files)

(Tested in .NET Core 2.1)

Here are the steps:

1. Delete the  `_efmigrationhistory` table.
2. Search for your entire solution for files that contain **Snapshot** in their name, such as `ApplicationDbContextSnapshot.cs`, and *delete* them.
3. Rebuild your solution
4. Run `Add-Migration InitialMigration`

Please note:
**You must delete ALL the Snapshot files**. I spent countless hours just deleting the database... This will generate an empty migration if you don't do it.

Also, in #3 you can just name your migration however you want.

Here are some additional resources:
[asp.net CORE Migrations generated empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915473/asp-net-core-migrations-generated-empty)

[Reset Entity Framework 7 migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009617/reset-entity-framework-7-migrations)

Answer (score 9):

**For EFCore 6/7:**

To merge all the changes over time back into a single file, and apply it to to existing databases while keeping all the data (i.e. in Production, and other devs) these steps worked for me:

1. Delete existing migrations from the `Migrations` Folder in your project.
2. Delete the Context Snapshop files. I.e. `ApplicationDbContextSnapshot.cs`,  `DatabaseContextModelSnapshot.cs` or similar.
3. Rebuild your solution
4. Run `Add-Migration Initial`. *(Can be named how you like instead of `Initial`). This will create a migration in your Migration folder that includes creating the tables, but won't be applied yet.*
5. Open the generated Migration file and `comment out all the code inside the "Up" method`, so that it doesn't make any changes to all your existing tables. *(This allows us to update the database in the correct format, without making any changes in the next step)*
6. Before the commented code within the Up function, add `migrationBuilder.Sql("DELETE FROM [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]");` to have the delete/truncate applied during migration

```
public partial class Initial : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("DELETE FROM [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]");
        /*
          OTHER COMMENTED OUT CODE
        */
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

7. Run `Update-Database`. *It will apply the Migration and remove existing migration tracking entriers (while not actually changing the database schema) and create a snapshot row in `__EFMigrationsHistory`*
8. Submit this code and apply to your dev, staging and production databases as you normally would *(Ensure the code is still commented out in the Up function, no changes will be applied, except a new entry created in `__EFMigrationsHistory`)*
9. Remove `migrationBuilder.Sql("DELETE FROM [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]");` and uncomment all the code from step 5 and submit back to source control. *(This way new devs can create the db from scratch. If someone forgot to update their existing database, it'll error out and complain that the tables already exist, so they can just comment the Initial file out and apply.)*

Answer (score 6):

**Delete** the **`Migrations`** Folder, **`Clean`** then **`Rebuild`** the project. This worked for me. Before Clean and Rebuild it was saying the Migration already exists since in its cached memory, it's not yet deleted.

Comment: Worked for me! Just note that after deleting the migrations folder you have to run enable-migrations again.

Answer (score 3):

In EntityFramework 6 please try:

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

in order to update the initial migration file.

Answer (score 3):

This method doesn't require deleting the `__MigrationHistory` table, so you don't have to put your hands on the database on deployment.

1. Delete existing migrations from the Migrations folder.
2. In Package Manager Console run `Add-Migration ResetMigrations`
3. Clean migration history in the `Up()` method:

```js
/// <summary>
/// Reset existing migrations by cleaning the __MigrationHistory table
/// and creating a new initial migration with the current model snapshot.
/// </summary>
public partial class ResetMigrations : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("DELETE FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for being meta and pragmatic and because I'm desperate and seriously considering this.

Answer (score 2):

My problem turned out to be that I manually removed the Migrations folder. I did that because I wanted to back up the contents, so I simply dragged the folder out of the project. I later fixed the problem by putting it back in (after making a backup copy), then removing the Migrations folder by right-clicking it in Solutions Explorer and choosing Delete from the popup menu.

Answer (score 1):

In EF6

1. Delete all your files in 'migrations' folder... But not the 'initial create' or 'config'.
2. Delete the database.
3. Now run `Add-Migration Initial`.
4. Now you can 'update-database' and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your db and code are synced and now just hung up on something simple like migrations trying to duplicate tasks, the easiest way to start over migrations without losing data is to:

1. Delete your Migrations folder in VS.
2. Create a new migration (e.g. `add-migration InitialCreate`)
3. Delete all but the first row from the `__EFMigrationsHistory` db and change the first row value to your first migration name with the date code (e.g. `20220510060015_InitialCreate`)

If you don't know the `ProductVersion` for the migration table, you can find it in the `Designer` or `Snaphot` `.cs` files in the newly created Migrations folder.

Now, when you run `update-database`, it should complete without erroring (and perform no tasks). This might be a good way to also get the most clean SQL migration script for an initial production environment if you were doing a bunch of renaming, dropping, tables, columns, etc. in your early migrations.

If your code and db are not in sync, depending on how much data you're dealing with and how out of sync they are, it's probably best to perform steps 1 and 2 above, then backup the db and drop it and let migrations recreate it all again from scratch, then restore the data.

[Microsoft: Managing Migrations - Resetting all migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#resetting-all-migrations)

To avoid the steps above, sometimes if a migration blows up midway through, you have to step through a migration and comment out each migrationBuilder block that's already completed (in the order they were created), especially if it's not clear from the migration error. So you can look at your db and see that tables, columns, FKs, indexes, etc. that have been dropped, renamed, created, etc. and then just go down the list of migrationBuilder blocks and step through the migration (comment out the completed steps, run update-database again, repeat). When you're done, uncomment everything.

Another common error you might run into if there's already data in the table and you're trying to add a FK constraint:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`Database1`.`#sql-alter-d9b-445b`, CONSTRAINT
> `FK_TableA_TableB_TableBId` FOREIGN KEY (`TableBId`) REFERENCES
> `TableB` (`TableBId)

The table you are trying to create a FK constraint for, it's FK constraint column doesn't match anything in the PK column of the primary table. It's best to prepare for this in advance by creating the PK table first with a default value placeholder, but if you already received the error then here we are. The easiest way to fix this to avoid some of the more drastic steps above is to:

1. Check to see if the FK column got created and if it assigned a default value (e.g. in TableA, FK constraint TableBId = "0").
2. Modify the PK table (or create it first) with a default PK Id record of whatever value was assigned in step 1 (e.g. in TableB, create a record with TableBId = "0").
3. Comment out everything before the `migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey` block that errored out and run `update-database` again. The migration should create the FK constraint now and complete.
4. Uncomment everything.

Answer (score 0):

**In Net Core 3.0:**

I was not able to find a way to *Reset Migrations*.

I also ran into problems with broken migrations, and the answers provided here didn't work for me.  I have a .Net Core 3.0 web API, and somewhere in the last month I edited the database directly. Yes, I did a bad, bad thing.

Strategies suggested here resulted in a number of errors in Package Manager Console:

- A migration of that name already exists
- Could not find the snapshot
- 'Force' is not a recognized parameter

Granted, I may have missed a step or missed clearing out the correct files, but I found that there are ways to clean this up without as much brute force:

- Remove-Migration from the PMC for each migration by name, in reverse order of creation, up to and including the broken migration
- Add-Migration to create a new migration which will be the delta between the last good migration up to the current schema

Now when the web API is started with an empty database, it correctly creates all the tables and properties to match the entity models.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2020 =>  Reset Entity-Framework Migrations

```
Add-Migration Initial -Context ApplicationDbContext
```

**ApplicationDbContext** => Your context.

But if you need only update a identity schema existent, try it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59966100/4654957

Comment: There's no context about what this is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

VSC(Visual Studio Code) -- .Net Core

1.Delete the state: Delete the migrations folder in your project;

2.Delete the __MigrationHistory's records in your database;

3.`dotnet ef database drop -v` then
Are you sure you want to drop the database '<your-database' on server '.'? (y/N)
Write "N"

4.dotnet ef migrations add Initial  then the code of the `20211014110429_initial` class  Write to __MigrationHistory's

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry you will not lose your data.
Follow me

1. Backup your database for safety.
2. Delete your Migrations folder.
3. Then go to SQL server and run this command in your database

   `Delete FROM [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]`
4. Then again come back to Visual Studio Project. and run the below command In the Package Manager Console.

   `PM> Add-migration Initial`
5. Here migration will be created in front of you remove the Up and Down code from here eg: below

`public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
             //remove all code
        }
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            //remove all code
        }
    }`

6. Last you can run the below command in Package Manager Console

   `PM> update-database`

Answer (score -2):

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force
```