# EF Migrations: Rollback last applied migration?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

This looks like a really common task, but I can't find an easy way to do it.

I want to undo the last applied migration. I would have expected a simple command, like

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:"-1"
```

Instead, all I can come up with is:

```
PM> Get-Migrations

Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
201208012131302_Add-SystemCategory
201207311827468_CategoryIdIsLong
201207232247409_AutomaticMigration
201207211340509_AutomaticMigration
201207200025294_InitialCreate

PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:"CategoryIdIsLong"
```

(At least I can use just the name, skipping the timestamp...)

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Sad, here we are years later and no one actually read the question.

Comment: I totally understand you!

Answer (score 260, accepted):

As of EF 5.0, the approach you describe is the preferred way. So

`PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:"NameOfSecondToLastMigration"`

or using your example migrations

`PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:"CategoryIdIsLong"`

One solution would be to create a wrapper PS script that automates the steps above. Additionally, feel free to create a feature request for this, or better yet, take a shot at implementing it! https://github.com/dotnet/ef6

Comment: Another detail: If you have an existing Manual Migration you need to roll back to, but realized your "Down" method doesn't really roll things back properly, you can just edit and save it, then rerun update-database -target... until it rolls back properly. Modifying the Manual Migration after the fact - after you've already applied it - doesn't turn it into something that's not allowed to be edited.

Comment: This does not work for me. All I get is "specified target migration "-1" does not exist.

Comment: @tutiplain Look at his second code block. You quoting what he wishes existed, not what does exist.

Comment: what is the correct way of doing this using dotnet command? Sorry i could not find in the documentation or i am missing something.  Tried via https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/cli-commands-for-ef-core-migration.aspx#migrations-remove

any suggestions?

Comment: I found the solution, `dotnet ef database update LastGoodMigration`, however, this seems confusing as I am coming from a node background and using knex, sequlize, they have a command to rever the last change, is there any command to revert the last action that was applied to the database?

Comment: -TargetMigration didn't work BUT -Migration did, EF Core 5.0.7

Answer (score 500):

I want to add some clarification to this thread:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"name_of_migration"
```

What you are doing above is saying that you want to rollback all migrations UNTIL you're left with the migration specified. Thus, if you use GET-MIGRATIONS and you find that you have A, B, C, D, and E, then using this command will rollback E and D to get you to C:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"C"
```

Also, unless anyone can comment to the contrary, I noticed that you can use an ordinal value and the short -Target switch (thus, -Target is the same as -TargetMigration). If you want to rollback all migrations and start over, you can use:

```
Update-Database -Target:0
```

0, above, would rollback even the FIRST migration (**this is a destructive command--be sure you know what you're doing before you use it!**)--something you cannot do if you use the syntax above that requires the name of the target migration (the name of the 0th migration doesn't exist before a migration is applied!). So in that case, you have to use the 0 (ordinal) value. Likewise, if you have applied migrations A, B, C, D, and E (in that order), then the ordinal 1 should refer to A, ordinal 2 should refer to B, and so on. So to rollback to B you could use either:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"B"
```

or

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:2
```

### Edit October 2019:

According to this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788279/6640527)  on a similar question, correct command is `-Target` for EF Core 1.1 while it is `-Migration` for EF Core 2.0.

Comment: The name of the migration with index 0 is `$InitialDatabase`.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any $(name) values to refer to other index positions, such as $LatestDatabase, or something like that?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't been able to find any by simple googling. Maybe browsing the EF source code would reveal them?

Comment: FYI, we just ran into this and were looking to do the same thing as OP... using `ls variable:*` it looks like `$InitialDatabase` is simply a PowerShell variable defined as 0, there aren't any other ones defined, even in the current EF source code. And, get-migrations doesn't return anything, it only writes to the console, so you can't iterate over the objects returned...

Comment: How do you update the model class to reflect the revert/newly executed migration?

Comment: The short -Target switch can be further abbreviated to -t. The migrations commands are PowerShell scripts. PowerShell script switches can be shorted to the fewest number of characters necessary to still be unique

Comment: In Visual Studio, I set the Package Manager Console to target default project `EntityFrameworkCore` and then I was able to use the command `Update-Database <<NameOfMigration>>`

Answer (score 147):

In **EntityFrameworkCore**:

```
Update-Database 20161012160749_AddedOrderToCourse
```

where `20161012160749_AddedOrderToCourse` is a name of migration you want to rollback to.

Comment: GEM! It took me a while to find this answer (as they've changed it for .NET Core). Definitely worth an upvote!

Comment: You don't need to include the date/time. You can just put in the name.

Comment: This does not work for me... it will say "Done" but all migrations after the one I specify still remain. And none of the "Down" code in any of those migrations has been executed.

Comment: one can also run back to a specific migration like that: 
Update-Database -Migration: "AddedOrderToCourse"
Especially when using blanks in migration names, this is the way to do it. (i.e. Update-Database -Migration "Added Order to Course")

Answer (score 70):

I realised there aren't any good solutions utilizing the CLI `dotnet` command so here's one:

```
dotnet ef migrations list
dotnet ef database update NameOfYourMigration
```

In the place of `NameOfYourMigration` enter the name of the migration you want to revert to.

Then you can remove all the reverted migrations for good using

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
```

Comment: Please remember, if you are going to use `dotnet ef`, make sure you have installed **dotnet-ef** tool.
To install,
`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`
For more information please visit [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet)

Answer (score 17):

The solution is:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration 201609261919239_yourLastMigrationSucess
```

Comment: This is already said in the question, the asker already knew this. I don't see how this helps, maybe you could make that clearer?

Comment: this answer is more concise. TY Max!

Answer (score 13):

**EF CORE**

`PM> Update-Database yourMigrationName`

(reverts the migration)

`PM> Update-Database`

worked for me

in this case the original question
(yourMigrationName = CategoryIdIsLong)

Comment: The previous solution doesn't work for EF Core , parameter error, whereas this two step solution worked, I was able to remove-migration after this whereas before I got an error message: The migration '20210201060139_cascadeDelete' has already been applied to the database. Revert it and try again. when remove-migration was tried.attempeted.

Answer (score 8):

```
update-database 0
```

***Warning***: This will roll back **ALL** migrations in EFCore! Please use with care :)

Answer (score 6):

I run mine through my **(BASH GIT) console** also running **Entity Framework Core**. `Update-Database` commands will not work outside of the package console and I have to use the `donet ef` commands.

```
donet ef database update [Name of previous Migration]
```

This will run the `protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` method of your current migration and all of the others to get back to the version of the DB you set it to.

I also use the `-p [migration project]` `-s [Project Solution]`. This also allows it to point to my **appsettings.[Enviorment].json** where my password to access DB is stored.

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=[ENVIORMENT]; donet ef database update [Name of previous Migration] -p [Migration Project Name] -s [Solution Name]
```

A lot of this might be known but wanted to give detail in case your first time doing.

Answer (score 5):

In EF Core you can enter the command `Remove-Migration` in the package manager console after you've added your erroneous migration.

The console suggests you do so if your migration could involve a loss of data:

> An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data.
>   Please review the migration for accuracy. To undo this action, use
>   Remove-Migration.

Comment: This only works when the migration hasn't been applied on the database yet.

Comment: This doesn't rollback the migration, this removes it from the migrations. If the migration is applied to the database, it doesn't change it, it just removes the migration from code.

Answer (score 4):

Additional reminder:

If you have multiple configuration type, you need to specify the [ConfigurationName]

```
Update-Database -Configurationtypename [ConfigurationName] -TargetMigration [MigrationName]
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that this works when run in the Package Manager Console:

`dotnet ef migrations list | select -Last 2 | select -First 1 | ForEach-Object { Update-Database -Migration $_ }`

You could create a script that makes it easier.

Answer (score 3):

EF CORE

Update database to the previous point

```
update-database CategoryIdIsLong
```

And then, remove the bad migration

```
remove-migration
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **EntityFrameworkCore** and I use the answer by @MaciejLisCK. If you have multiple DB contexts you will also need to specify the context by adding the context parameter e.g. :

`Update-Database 201207211340509_MyMigration -context myDBcontext`

(where `201207211340509_MyMigration` is the migration you want to roll back to, and `myDBcontext` is the name of your DB context)

Answer (score 2):

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration:"Your migration name"
```

For this problem I suggest this link:

https://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/

Answer (score 1):

If you work with EF Core on daily basis, you might find [efmig](https://github.com/stil/efmig) tool useful.

After you have configured your database and project details, you just click "Generate rollback script"

[image: efmig main window]

after a couple of seconds, it'll generate and show SQL script for you to review and apply:
[image: sql script]

After applying the rollback script, you can use "Remove from code" action to remove migration code from project.
I think it's as simple as it gets.

Disclaimer: I'm the author, the project is open source and I've been using it at my daily work for long time now.

Answer (score 0):

In case there is a possibility for dataloss EF does not complete the update-database command since AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false by default, and roolbacks the action unless you run it with the *-force* parameter.

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration:"Your migration name" -force
```

or

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration:Your_Migration_Index -force
```

Answer (score 0):

##### This solution is effective within a project that is dependent on Entity Framework Core 7.

```
Remove-Migration -Force
```

This command will:

- Reverts the effects of the most recently applied migration on the database **without** necessitating the use of the "Update-Database" command.
- Deletes the associated migrations and snapshots.

## IMPORTANT

> Kindly note that executing this command will **not prompt for
> confirmation**. The most recently generated **migration** and its related
> **database changes** will be **reversed**.
>
> If the migration being rolled back involves the **removal of columns or
> tables**, it's important to recognize that there is a possibility of
> **data loss**. Any information stored within the columns or tables
> affected by the removed migration **will be lost without any confirmation prompt**.

If your application utilizes multiple DbContexts, simply include the name of the targeted DbContext in the command:

```
Remove-Migration -context <SecondDbContext> -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with following solution:
When EF creates a migration there are two methods there - `Up()` and `Down()` and my solution is based on swapping names for these methods.
So, when I need to roll back on that migration I simply rename and `Up()` method to `Down()` and vice versa.
And it works.