# error on update-database -force -verbose

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am changing my model names and I must of done something that interferes with the package-manager. I'm getting an error after I do an

> update-database -force -verbose

I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.
```

The application builds but I'm wondering how do I correct this so I can use the package-manager to update my database.

The command that it is trying to run is the following:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.piQuestion', @newname = N'Question', @objtype = N'OBJECT'
```

I changed my table name from `piQuestion` to `Question` already.  So I understand why this isn't working.

**So my question is how do I tell the package manager that this table has already been changed?**

Comment: have you addressed what the error is suggesting? Is @objname ambiguous? Could it have been used more than once?

Comment: The question suggested doesn't really answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to reset the migration state completely so that the current state is the initial state, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations) describes a way. This is applicable if you won't need to rollback from this state.

Another method is to [rollback to the previous migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904571/ef-migrations-rollback-last-applied-migration) then redo.