# Entity framework Core Update-database specific migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out how to run a specific migration from the package manager in nuget.

I have tried to run:

```
 update-database -TargetMigration test32
```

But I do get this message:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TargetMigration'.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

According to [EF Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell), correct parameter name is `-Target` (for EF Core 1.1) or `-Migration` (for EF Core 2.0)

so in your case:

```
update-database -target test32
```

or

```
update-database -migration test32
```

"Modern" way is to use "regular" command prompt and [.NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet), and command like `dotnet ef database update <target>`

Comment: I don't approve of your second comment. :) Both the Package Manager Console and .NET Command Line Tools are equally legit.

Comment: Sorry Brice :) I absolutely agree that both are legit, but PMConsole have long history (from VS 2013 or even earlier?), while CLI is more new/young and cross-platform, so I used word "modern"  (beer)

Comment: there is no target parameter

Comment: @Dmitry do you know how to do this via C# code?

Comment: There is no -target parameter . Please remove it.

Answer (score 89):

The best answer given by Dmitry is a bit incorrect.
There's no parameter `-Target`. The only parameter that can be applied is `-Migration`.
Therefore, the right answer is:

```
Update-Database -Migration test32
```

Comment: Can confirm.  core 2.0 uses -migration.  -target is no longer reconized

Comment: This applies all the missing migrations up to the provided one (`test32`), which is what you normally want since migrations might one upon the other and must be run in order.

Answer (score 28):

For EF Core 3.1 via Package Manager Console:

```
dotnet ef database update YourMigrationName
```

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add to what Plastiquewind mentioned.  In the current version, there is no -target parameter. You have to use -migration.  Also, you can specify the context (if you have more than one) with the -context parameter.

```
Update-database -context MyContext -migration MyMigration
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac OS i did like this working for me

```
dotnet ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext
```