# Is there a plural issue for models database context y to ies in mvc4 EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I keep getting error when I try to access a model from an edit or details action.

> The model backing the 'InjuriesContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

First I tried adding a migration even though I was sure I hadn't changed anything.  Still recieved the same error after an update-database.

Then I removed all the migrations and the database and started a clean database with an inital migration and update.  Same error.  Nothing was changed.

Model is:

```
public class InjuriesContext : DbContext
    {
        public InjuriesContext()
            : base("DBCon")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Injury> Injuries { get; set; }
    }

    public class Injury
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is controller --

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Injury injury = db.Injuries.Find(id);
            if (injury == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(injury);
        }
```

It errors on the injuries.find.  I do not have any injuries entered so I expect it to return a 404 like my other controllers but it doesn't like something about this.  The only difference between this and my other models is the y to ies for plural.  Does Entity Framework not handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "an inital migration and update"? Don't you want you map the table name manually? (Although that would only evade the issue).

Comment: @GertArnold I ran and intial add migration and update database through entity framework so it would create the tables.  I am not sure what you mean my map the table name manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my issue was with multiple contexts.  I thought you had to create a separate context for each model class.  Apparently Entity Framework needs one context.  I went through and created a class for my context and put all my DBsets in that class.

```
    public class ProjContexts : DbContext
    {
         public ProjContexts()
            : base("ProjDBCon")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PreHosp> PreHosps { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Injury> Injuries { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then I removed all the migrations as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations) and enabled the migrations again did an add migration and update then I got the expected result.

Bottom Line--- Don't have multiple context classes in your project.  Not sure if this is possible but after changing the above everything is working as expected.  Not sure why it was working when I had two separate contexts and added the third?  Maybe because they had foreign keys with one another?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any plural restriction, as you defined everything clearly in your classes anyway.

Have you created the Injuries table?

I belive the table Injury will get created automatically. the variable injury might be a bit close, but I have to test this myself.

Rather try:

```
public class Injury
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
}


    private InjuriesContext db = new InjuriesContext();
    Injury objInjury = db.Injuries.Find(id);
    if (objInjury == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(objInjury);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes EF created the Injuries table when I ran the initial migration.  I tried the above and got the same error.  I am at a loss.  I just created a different controller, without the ies and it works fine.

Comment: Strike the last.  Having the same issue on a controller/model without the ies and just S.  Not sure what happened.  The tables created have all the correct fields so I don't know what it thinks has changed?

Comment: Thanks did find out there is no issue with the plural as mentioned here but the root issue is answered above.  +1 for the help.