# Code-first migrations says there are pending changes while there aren't any

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

So I'm trying to run the `database update` in MVC 5 within an MVC action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDatabase(UpdateDatabaseModel updateDatabaseModel)
{
    DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration
    {
        TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo("DefaultConnection"),
        ContextType = typeof(ApplicationDbContext),
        MigrationsAssembly = typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly
    };

    var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationsConfiguration);
    migrator.Update(updateDatabaseModel.SelectedMigration);
    return this.View("ManageApplication");
 }
```

The problem is, at `migrator.Update(updateDatabaseModel.SelectedMigration);` it throws an error:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

But when I do an `add-migration`, the `Up()` and `Down()` are empty (also after adding this migration, it still throws that exception)

Any idea?

I also checked this one: [EF Add-Migration indicates "No pending explicit migrations" but Update-Database complains "..there are pending changes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110670/ef-add-migration-indicates-no-pending-explicit-migrations-but-update-database) but the namespaces are okay.

Comment: Delete _MigrationHistory table and then try

Comment: @viveknuna makes no difference. still "pending changes"-message

Comment: Can you delete your database? and then try if possible ?

Comment: @viveknuna been there, done that :D still same problem. also tried with setting Initializer to null and start without existing database...

Comment: I think you can try enable automatic migration

Comment: @viveknuna that's what I don't want to do. I really want to do those migrations manually.

Comment: But I think thats the only option which is striking me fow now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the correct solution is easy:

When enabling migrations, in the newly created namespace `Migrations` the class `Configuration` is created. This class inherits from `DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>` and this inherits from `DbMigrationsConfiguration`. So, we don't need to create an instance with `new DbMigrationsConfiguration()` but with that generated `new Configuration()`.

the correct code is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateDatabase(UpdateDatabaseModel updateDatabaseModel)
{
    DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration = new Configuration();

    var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationsConfiguration);
    migrator.Update(updateDatabaseModel.SelectedMigration);
    return this.View("ManageApplication");
 }
```

and that's it.