# Entitfy Framework: everything is broken when I change schema

Tags: entity-framework

I use EF with code-first approach.

I have a class:

```
public class Cat {
// ...
}
```

Then I add some properties and migrations for them. So I have a couple of existing migrations. Then I create abstract class:

```
public abstract class Animal {
// ...
}
```

And inherit a Cat from Animal:

```
public Cat : Animal {
// ...
}
```

When I do that, and run add-migration I run into the problem I can't solve. EF gives me an error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following
>   explicit migrations are pending: [...]. Apply the pending explicit
>   migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

This is because schema is stored in __MigrationHistory. And when EF tries to compare the current schema with schema fetched from database (from __MigrationHistory), it fails.

Everything's fine when I drop all of Migrations and create the database from scratch.

But I don't want to drop the entire database when schema changes.

How can I handle schema changes with EF?

Here is [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952413/stuck-in-ef-migration-limbo), but without any good solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you ran `Add-Migration` and didn't run `Update-Database` then run it.

But some times you run following command:

```
PM>add-migration migration1
```

Then make some changes to your model, in this case if you want to add another migration, you get mentioned error, so you have 2 options:

1. Run `Update-Database` to apply pending changes of migration1 to database and then add new migration.
2. Run `add-migration migration1 -force` to add all pending migrations as migration1 and then run `update-database`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Update-Database before you run Add-Migration