# error loading database initializer with EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have been trying to follow this tutorial ... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application but I keep getting the following error ...

> system.invalidoperationexception = {"Failed to set database
>   initializer of type 'WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingInitializer,
>   KevinLisaWedding' for DbContext type
>   'WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext' specified in the application
>   configuration. See inner exception for details."}

The inner exception is ...

> {"Could not load type 'WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext' from
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":"WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext"}

The stack trace is ...

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.<>c__DisplayClass6.<TryGetInitializerFromEntityFrameworkSection>b__1(ContextElement e)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializerFromEntityFrameworkSection(Type contextType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type contextType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at KevinLisaWedding.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\kdonde\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KevinLisaWedding\KevinLisaWedding\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 14
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
```

I've also searched high and low for why I am getting this error without any luck and I've downloaded the completed project and compared it to mine without any luck.

My current code is as follows.

In the WeddingPreparations project ...

```
namespace WeddingPreparations.Dal
{
    public class WeddingContext : DbContext
    {
        public WeddingContext()
            : base("WeddingContext")  
        {

        }

        // Any entities reference by this class will be implicitly included.
        public DbSet<Invitee> Invitees { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace WeddingPreparations.Dal
{
    public class WeddingInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<WeddingContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(WeddingContext context)
        {
            //base.Seed(context);
            var invitees = new List<Invitee>
            {
                new Invitee{ FirstName= "FName1", LastName= "LName1", Attending = true, HotelRoomRequired= true, Notes="I'm the groom! :)"},
                new Invitee{ FirstName= "FName2", LastName= "LName2", Attending = true, HotelRoomRequired= true, Notes="I'm the bride! :)"}

            };
            invitees.ForEach(i => context.Invitees.Add(i));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

My model in this project is as follows

```
namespace WeddingPreparations.Models
{
    public class Invitee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool Attending { get; set; }
        public bool HotelRoomRequired { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
     }
}
```

In the mvc project I have the following web.config file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WeddingContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=WeddingInvites;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext">
        <databaseInitializer type="WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingInitializer, KevinLisaWedding" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" >
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0"/>
    </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And in my home controller I'm executing the following code ...

```
WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext ctx = new WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext();
var x = ctx.Invitees.ToList();
```

which is supposed to create the database if I'm not mistaking and seed it with the data specified in the initializer ... however all I get is that error and I can't seem to figure it out ... any direction is appreciated.

## Update

I tried recreating the project as one just like they did in the tutorial and but i still end up with the same error. There's gotta be some code missing ... either I missed it ... or the tutorial just doesn't have it.

Comment: What is the name of the assembly being created? Is it WeddingPreparations or KevinLisaWedding?

Comment: KevinLisaWedding is the website project and WeddingPreparations is the dll with the entity models and entity framework context etc.

Comment: Does it work if you set the initializer in the `DbContext` constructor, like this: `Database.SetInitializer(new WeddingInitializer());`

Comment: Thanks david004 I have tried as you suggested but still ended up with the same error. I not sure if there is perhaps more information that I can provide.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your `web.config` file you have this:

```
<contexts>
    <context type="WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext">
        <databaseInitializer type="WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingInitializer, KevinLisaWedding" />
    </context>
</contexts>
```

This says look for a class called `WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingInitializer` in the assembly called `KevinLisaWedding`. As your assembly is called `WeddingPreparations` you need to change the config to this:

```
<contexts>
    <context type="WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingContext, WeddingPreparations">
        <databaseInitializer type="WeddingPreparations.Dal.WeddingInitializer, WeddingPreparations" />
    </context>
</contexts>
```

Comment: DavidG I had actually tried that a few times. I just switched it again and I still get the same error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try specifying the context type in there too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just ran into the exact same problem after checking and double checking. Context type is so important.

Thanks!

Comment: Or if you defined 'Execute code first migrations' in your publish-settings you have to re-generate you publish after changing the namespace of your context!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same tutorial. The Initializer class was not added to the project. Add it to the project file or right click in the Solution Explorer and click "Include"