# MVC Database First Failed to set database initializer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and I have already created Database after we generated the ADO entity data model called HRContextEntities and we created just a bankviewmodel and its Repository and its Index view to display the Database Banks in a List:

**Context** :

```
 public partial class HRContextEntities : DbContext
    {
        public HRContextEntities()
            : base("name=HRContextEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ACTIONS> ACTIONS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BANKS> BANKS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_ALAWA> EMP_ALAWA { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_CARDS> EMP_CARDS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_DAORA> EMP_DAORA { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_DEGREES> EMP_DEGREES { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_DEGREES_WORKERS> EMP_DEGREES_WORKERS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_DISSENT> EMP_DISSENT { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_EMPLOYEES> EMP_EMPLOYEES { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_ENDEMP> EMP_ENDEMP { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_ENTEDAB> EMP_ENTEDAB { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_EQRAR> EMP_EQRAR { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_HASMIAT> EMP_HASMIAT { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_HOLIDAYS> EMP_HOLIDAYS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EMP_JOBS> EMP_JOBS { get; set; }
        ...............................
```

**Bank View Model** :

```
public class BankViewModel
{
    public decimal BankID { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string BankSymbol { get; set; }
}
```

**Bank Repository** class:

```
public class BankRepository
{
    HRContextEntities db = new HRContextEntities();
     public BankViewModel[] GetAll(int? take, int? skip)
    {
        return db.BANKS.Select(s => new BankViewModel { BankID = s.ID, BankName = s.NAME })
            .OrderBy(s => s.BankID).Skip(skip != null ? skip.Value : 0)
            .Take(take != null ? take.Value : int.MaxValue).ToArray();
    }
}
```

**_Banks Partial View** from:

```
@model IEnumerable<HumanResourceManagement.Models.BankViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="odd gradeX">

    <td>
        @item.BankID
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.BankName
    </td>
    <td>
        RYD
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

**Exception**:

`Additional information: Failed to set database initializer of type 'MyProject.Context.Config.ContextInitializer, MyProject.Context' for DbContext type 'App.Context.Default, App.Context' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.`

**web.config**

```
<contexts>
      <context type="App.Context.Default, App.Context">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.Context.Config.ContextInitializer, MyProject.Context" />
        <!--<databaseInitializer type="MyProject.Context.Config.ContextInitializer, MyProject.Context" />-->

      </context>
    </contexts>
```

so what is the solution for this exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error loading database initializer with EF6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542605/error-loading-database-initializer-with-ef6)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your web.config file:

```
<contexts>
    <context type="App.Context.Default, App.Context">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.Context.Config.ContextInitializer, MyProject.Context" />                
    </context>
</contexts>
```

The `context type` specifies the fully qualified context class name and the assembly it's in, and the `databaseinitializer` type specifies the fully qualified name of the initializer class and the assembly it's in. [Read this for more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606#Initializers).

Basically, the second param for context type AND databaseinitializer should be the **project assembly**, not the context. So it should follow this pattern:

```
<context type=" Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly"> 
   <databaseInitializer type="Blogging.MyCustomBlogInitializer, MyAssembly" /> 
</context>
```

So in your code, try this (I think your assembly is MyProject):

```
<contexts>
    <context type="MyProject.App.Context, MyProject">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.Context.Config.ContextInitializer, MyProject" />                
    </context>
</contexts>
```