# Encoutering problem when updating second migration with a different name in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, database-migration

I am trying to add and update second migration in asp.net core with a different name from Initial Migration, but during update-database the error says There is already an object named 'Values' in the database. How can I can I update the new Entity and not update the Values object.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a problem in migration process,
 run add-migration command in "Package Manager Console"

```
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```

do some changes, and then update database from "Initial" file:

```
Update-Database -verbose
```

For more details refer this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687656/495455

Comment: I have added Add-Migration "InitialCreate" but I also wanna add this: Add-Migration AddUserEntity, this is not working Add-Migration AddUserEntity -IgnoreChanges it gives error. I can Add the migration in one migration but I wanna track down those migrations

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I finally find a solution. I had to remove all migrations and it worked perfectly with different name for the second migration