# Database update isn't available because of an error "there is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a problem when I try to update my database in cmd it shows an error

> "There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database".

I tried to solve this problem with option "Add-Migration InitialMigrations -IgnoreChanges" in Package Manager Console, but there is also an error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IgnoreChanges'". Probably, is it because my project is based on EF Core, but "IgnoreChanges" is available only in EF6? How can I solve this problem to have opportunity to update database?
[image]

[image]

Comment: check this one first : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687433/update-database-command-is-not-working-in-asp-net-core-entity-framework-core-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround:

- create a new migration
- comment or empty the Up and Down methods
- update database
- new changes can be added to the following migrations