# How do I create a review entity as a child of a parent entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'd like to create a `Review` entity so users can review and rate a user (profile) entity for my social site. But the problem I'm having is when trying to insert a review into the table I get an exception; something about a foreign key conflicting with `ProfileId` in the `Profile` table. So I'm not sure if the syntax is correct here for creating the entities and their relationships?

Here is my code

```
public class Profile 
{
    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }    // one to many
}

public class Review
{
    [Key]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    public int ProfileRefId { get; set; }

    // one-to-many here
    [ForeignKey("ProfileRefId")]
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string body {get; set; }
    public int Rating {get; set; }

    // here is where I want to set the reviewer to a user (profile entity), 
    //   but not sure about the syntax
    [ForeignKey("ReviewerProfile ")]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile ReviewerProfile { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to insert here is what I do.

```
var reviewer = dbContext.Profiles.Where(i => i.ApplicationUserId == userId).First();
Review reviewer = new Review
                      {
                          Created = DateTime.Now,
                          ReviewerProfile = reviewer
                      };

profile.Reviewers.Add(reviewer);

// then save...
```

Comment: doesn't anyone have any input here! this seems like a simple problem that has occurred before, surely I'm not the first who has needed this!

Comment: You have two references to `Profile` table in `Review` class: `public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }` & `public virtual Profile ReviewerProfile { get; set; }`. Choose one which you want to keep & set `ForeignKeyAttribute` to its PK field.

Comment: You are not updating `reviewer.Profile`

Comment: I'm not sure what you guys mean, can you please further explain your comments?

Comment: this link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570916/defining-multiple-foreign-key-for-the-same-table-in-entity-framework-code-first gave me the answer I needed.