# Reset Entity Framework 7 migrations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework 7 beta 5. I started with the mvc template with user management. I have added several migrations, during my trials.

Now I want to delete my database, create a new initial migration and produce a new clean db with it.

However the dnx ef commands do not have a command that I know of that will facilitate this. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What exactly do you need support from EF for? Here's what I'd do:

- Delete your database
- Delete all your migrations
- Configure the context to point to your new, clean 
  database
- Run `dotnet ef migrations add <initial-migration-name>`

Comment: Think that will probably work. Found some thing in the rather verbose output about Identities not being right. I'm trying to use a guid as primary key which set via property initilizer

Comment: I just deleted the context snapshot in the migrations folder too and it worked (ef7 rc1)

Comment: Can you update your answer to accommodate for EF Core?

Comment: The only difference should be that `dnx .` is replaced by `dotnet`