# Entity Framework Core - change schema of "__EFMigrationsHistory" table

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is it possible to change schema of `__EFMigrationsHistory` table in EntityFramework Core?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Do it in your call to `UseSqlServer`.

```
optionsBuilder
    .UseSqlServer(
        "...",
        x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable(
            HistoryRepository.DefaultTableName,
            "mySchema"));
```

Comment: Nice one. Simplier. Thanks.

Comment: @bricelam Could you also then change the column names of the migrations history table?

Comment: @AlexBello Answered [in a blog post](http://www.bricelam.net/2017/01/04/efcore-history-table.html).

Comment: @bricelam Before you responded, I had created [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41449653/2161572) specifically about the column names. I'm not sure if you want to answer it there as well, in case anyone else searching specifically for renaming the columns can find it easily.

Answer (score 12):

Looking into source code ([HistoryRepository.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/release/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Migrations/HistoryRepository.cs)). You can configure custom migrations table and schema names, inside `DbContext constructor`

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
    var relationalOptions = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(options);
    relationalOptions.MigrationsHistoryTableName = "bar";
    relationalOptions.MigrationsHistoryTableSchema = "foo";
}
```

or inside `OnConfiguring method`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var relationalOptions = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(optionsBuilder.Options);
    relationalOptions.MigrationsHistoryTableName = "bar";
    relationalOptions.MigrationsHistoryTableSchema = "foo";
}
```

Comment: Very close. I've taken it one step further in my answer.

Comment: Looks like MS changed it to:  WithMigrationsHistoryTableName("bar") and WithMigrationsHistoryTableSchema("foo") in case anyone searches for this later.

Comment: @JasonRoner according to the implementation, that just creates a new RelationalOptions with that property set. How do we absorb this new object back into our configuration? (also the docs remark that it is unusual to call this directly and we are referred back to DbContextOptionsBuilder, but with no guidance on how to achieve the same effect there)