# Change MigrationsHistoryTable column names in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a standardized all table and column names in my EF Core database to use snake_case. I was able to change the migrations history table name and schema to match the rest of the database, but I am not able to find a way to change the columns from `MigrationId` to `migration_id` and `ProductVersion` to `product_version`.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it on SQL Server.

First, create a custom implementation of `SqlServerHistoryRepository` overriding `ConfigureTable`.

```cs
class MyHistoryRepository : SqlServerHistoryRepository
{
    public MyHistoryRepository(
        IDatabaseCreator databaseCreator, IRawSqlCommandBuilder rawSqlCommandBuilder,
        ISqlServerConnection connection, IDbContextOptions options,
        IMigrationsModelDiffer modelDiffer,
        IMigrationsSqlGenerator migrationsSqlGenerator,
        IRelationalAnnotationProvider annotations,
        ISqlGenerationHelper sqlGenerationHelper)
        : base(databaseCreator, rawSqlCommandBuilder, connection, options,
            modelDiffer, migrationsSqlGenerator, annotations, sqlGenerationHelper)
    {
    }

    protected override void ConfigureTable(EntityTypeBuilder<HistoryRow> history)
    {
        base.ConfigureTable(history);

        history.Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasColumnName("migration_id");
        history.Property(h => h.ProductVersion).HasColumnName("product_version");
    }
}
```

Then replace the replace the service with your custom implementation.

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    => options
        .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
        .ReplaceService<SqlServerHistoryRepository, MyHistoryRepository>();
```

Comment: Looking at the `SqlServerHistoryRepository` it doesn't seem to have an easy way to use one migration table for multiple db contexts on the same table (i.e. by adding a kind of discriminator field)?

Comment: Unless your migration IDs conflict (very unlikely since they're timestamped down to the second and user named) you shouldn't need a discriminator field.