# EF Core Migrations with multiple DbContexts on single database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have an issue attempting to use Migrations in a ASP.NET Core solution using EF Core where there are multiple `DbContext` that share the same SQL database.

In my application startup method I'm getting a reference to each context and calling the `context.Database.Migrate()` method. However as both of these contexts are pointing to the same underlying database I'm getting the error:

> There is already an object named '__EFMigrationsHistory' in the database.

Here's a MCVE:

```
class DbContextA : DbContext {}
class DbContextB : DbContext {}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var contextA = GetContextFromDIContainer<DbContextA>();
  var contextB = GetContextFromDIContainer<DbContextB>();

  contextA.Database.Migrate();
  contextB.Database.Migrate();
}

void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<DbContextA>(opt =>
  {
    opt.UseSqlServer("connectionstring");
  });

  services.AddDbContext<DbContextB>(opt =>
  {
    opt.UseSqlServer("connectionstring");
  });
}
```

Note that each `DbContext` exists in a separate assembly in which the Migrations are configured.

I am able to manually execute the respective migrations with the `Update-Database` CLI tool but it doesn't seem to work as part of my app startup code.

Is there a way to execute migrations on both contexts at runtime and bypass the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table creation if already exists?

Comment: @Fabio The `__EFMigrationsHistory` table isn't an entity of mine it's implicitly created by EF to manage which migrations to apply.

Comment: just make sure you use unique migration names when generating the migrations, I think the problem must be 2 dbcontexts with migrations named alike

Comment: Which version of EF Core are you using? Which Provider? As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449653/change-migrationshistorytable-column-names-in-ef-core/41596101#comment77848234_41596101) multiple dbcontext on same database (and even same schema) shouldn't cause any issues

Comment: also make sure they have unique table names

Comment: @JoeAudette The migration names are absolutely unique between contexts.

Comment: @Tseng EF Core `2.0.2`, Provider is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think your problem is just two Context try to use same migration history table

try specific your migration history table for each

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
=> options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__MyMigrationsHistoryForDBContextA", "mySchema"));
```

it should be fix

[Custom Migrations History Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table)

Comment: Multiple Contexts using the same **database** shouldn't be an issue as pointed by @bricelam in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41596101/455493). So you are maybe doing something "funky" and the two contexts share the same migration IDs?

Comment: I mean just separate migration history for each context it will be fixed, because two context try to create same migration history table name and the two table with same name same schema are not allowed

Comment: I have multiple dbcontexts from different assemblies working fine in my projects and they all use the same migration history table, seems weird to have to do that.

Comment: I agree with @JoeAudette, something strange seems about that setup. While it max fix the immediate problem, it won't fix the root of problem of it.

Comment: @JoeAudette How are you executing the migrations in your scenario?

Comment: @ChrisPickford for example see the method EnsureDataStorageIsReady in my Program.cs [here](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/sourceDev.WebApp/Program.cs) it calls multiple static methods in different assemblies and each one does migrations like [this](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Storage.EFCore.Common/SimpleContentEFStartup.cs)