EF Core multitenancy, different schema. EF Core does not change the table schema when the API is at runtime
I'm developing a multi-tenant ASP.NET Core Web API project and I use EF Core 8 as my ORM and SQL Server. The project supports several tenants and I need to create the databases at run time and change the schema from dbo to "the Brazilian cpf document number".
I already have a migration ready. When the project is running and I run Migrate(), it creates the database correctly, but does not change the schema. EF Core insists on maintaining dbo for the tables and does not obey the parameters that I inform.
Does anyone have any idea what it is? I've tried everything and I've been at it for over 5 months with no solution.
//Apply Migrations
public static void Test(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration, TenantRequestViewModel tenantRequestViewModel)
{
    using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var currentTenantRepo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICurrentTenantRepository>();

        if (!currentTenantRepo.SetTenantAsync(tenantRequestViewModel.DocumentNumber).Result) { { } }

        string dbName = DataBaseConst.DATABASE_NAME_ERP_VET + "-" + tenantRequestViewModel.DocumentNumber;
        string defaultConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        string connectionString = currentTenantRepo.ConnectionString ?? defaultConnectionString.Replace(DataBaseConst.DATABASE_NAME_ERP_VET, dbName);

        var appDbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        appDbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        var mediatorHandler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediatorHandler>();

        using (var appDbContext = new AppDbContext(appDbContextOptionsBuilder.Options, currentTenantRepo, mediatorHandler, currentTenantRepo.Schema))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Current Schema: {currentTenantRepo.Schema}");

            if (appDbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
            {
                appDbContext.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }       
    }
}

// My Context
public sealed class AppDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IMediatorHandler _mediatorHandler;

    private readonly ICurrentTenantRepository _currentTenantRepository;
    public Guid CurrentTenantId { get; set; }
    public string? CurrentTenantConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string? CurrentSchema { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, ICurrentTenantRepository currentTenantRepository, IMediatorHandler mediatorHandler, string? schema = null) : base(options)
    {
        _mediatorHandler = mediatorHandler;
        _currentTenantRepository = currentTenantRepository;

        if (_currentTenantRepository is not null)
        {
            CurrentTenantId = _currentTenantRepository.TenantId;
            CurrentTenantConnectionString = _currentTenantRepository.ConnectionString;
            CurrentSchema = string.IsNullOrEmpty(schema) ? _currentTenantRepository.Schema : schema ;
        }

        //ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        //ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<ValidationResult>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Event>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<CreateTenantRequest>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<TenantResponse>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Tenant>();

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(CurrentSchema);
        
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentSchema))
        {
            foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                entityType.SetSchema(CurrentSchema);
            }              
        }           

        foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(
            e => e.GetProperties().Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string))))
            property.SetColumnType("varchar(100)");
            
        //Schema name passed to table configuration
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerMap(CurrentSchema));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    // On Configuring -- dynamic connection string, fires on every request
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string? tenantConnectionString = CurrentTenantConnectionString;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantConnectionString)) // use tenant db if one is specified
        {
            _ = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(tenantConnectionString);
        }

        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, CustomModelCacheKeyFactory>();

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}

// CustomModelCacheKeyFactory
public class CustomModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    public object Create(DbContext context, bool designTime)
    {
        var contextWithSchema = context as AppDbContext;
        // O TenantId ou schema específico pode ser utilizado como chave, junto com o designTime.
        return (contextWithSchema?.CurrentSchema, context.GetType(), designTime);
    }
}



{
  "documentNumber": "03350593097",
  "workspaceName": "My_Work_1", 
  "phoneNumber": "27996356704", 
  "email": "jalberromano@msn.com",
  "password": "123456",
  "confirmPassword": "123456",  
  "subscriptionPlanId": "0335a5fe-4754-4ed0-1434-08dd1937d5aa",//after starting the API get the ID from the table
  "cultureCode": "pt-BR",
  "isolated": true
}

The project is big and I can't post the entire source here. You can download it.

Sorry, there is way too much code for me to read here. You will likely get a much quicker answer if you supply a [mre] (with the stress on the "minimal")

5 months? Well I'll answer tomorrow, it is possible by replacing and extending  internal service. I'm talking about only migrations which are highly customisable if there is no direct SQL calls.

AFAIK you won't be able to manage a single set of migrations across multiple SQL Server  schemas. At a minimum each tenant would need its own __Migrations table (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527157/ef-core-migrations-with-multiple-dbcontexts-on-single-database) where you pass a schema name to the DbContext this would also factor into its migration table name. The migrations themselves would need to ensure each schema is created, and the CreateTable etc. also need to reference the specific schema run. Personally I avoid code-first / migrations due to complexities like this.

Thanks guys! This API is prepared to support two types of tenants: Single-tenant and Multi-tenant. Both ways work perfectly, however, they have the problem of not setting the name of the dbo schema to the name I provide.

@rj-, preparing answer, so you need to apply Migrations to tenant's schema, I'm right?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Exactly. All tenants will have the same type of database, therefore, a migration when applied (myContext.Migrate()) must change all databases (Single-tenant and Multi-tenant), as this project works in both ways. If you notice in my project, I am instantiating the context in the "MultipleDatabaseExtensions" class through the "Test" method. This is where I need to create the new database at runtime. As the project uses the DDD concept, I believe you will have no difficulty understanding it. If you have any questions, feel free to ask me. Thank you very much!

I have created a small console application demonstrating how to configure EF Core to generate migrations for different schemas while still leveraging the default schema's migration generation. The classes are organized logically, and their dependencies will be explained later.
Program.cs Example: Combining Everything
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "Server=localhost,1419;Database=SOMultitenancy;User Id=sa;Password=Password12!;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true";

        using var context1 = CreateTenantContext(connectionString, "tenant1");
        using var context2 = CreateTenantContext(connectionString, "tenant2");
        using var context3 = CreateTenantContext(connectionString, "tenant3");
        
        context1.Database.Migrate();
        context2.Database.Migrate();  
        context3.Database.Migrate();

        // At this point we have all tenants configured and all tables are created

        var o1 = context1.Orders.ToArray();
        var o2 = context2.Orders.ToArray();
        var o3 = context3.Orders.ToArray();
    }

    private static AppDbContext CreateTenantContext(string connectionString, string? tenantName)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServerMultiTenant(connectionString, tenantName, AppDbContextModelConfiguration.BuildModel)
            .LogTo(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

        var context = new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        return context;
    }
}

Define test context
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }


    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

Define AppDbContextFactory which helps to generate migrations for Console applications.
DON'T forget to install package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
public class AppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of AppDbContext for design-time tools like migrations.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Command-line arguments.</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of AppDbContext.</returns>
    public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        // Define the connection string
        var connectionString = "Server=localhost,1419;Database=SOMultitenancy;User Id=sa;Password=Password12!;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true";

        // Configure DbContextOptions
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServerMultiTenant(connectionString, null, AppDbContextModelConfiguration.BuildModel);

        return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

Model Configuration
You should move model configuring into this class
public static class AppDbContextModelConfiguration
{
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IModel> ModelCache = new();

    public static ModelBuilder CreateModelBuilder()
    {
        // Create the ModelBuilder with the SQL Server conventions
        var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(ModelBuildingHelper.GetSqlServerConventionSet());

        return modelBuilder;
    }

    public static IModel BuildModel(string? schemaName = default)
    {
        schemaName ??= string.Empty;

        if (ModelCache.TryGetValue(schemaName, out var model))
            return model;

        var modelBuilder = CreateModelBuilder();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schemaName))
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schemaName);

        ConfigureModel(modelBuilder);
        model = modelBuilder.FinalizeModel();

        ModelCache.TryAdd(schemaName, model);

        return model;
    }

    private static void ConfigureModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Customer entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
            entity.HasMany(e => e.Orders)
                .WithOne(o => o.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.CustomerId);
        });

        // Configure Order entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entity.Property(e => e.OrderDate).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.Amount).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
        });
    }
}

Helper for SQL Server Conventions
public static class ModelBuildingHelper
{
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
    private static ConventionSet? _sqlServerConventionSet = null;

    public static ConventionSet GetSqlServerConventionSet()
    {
        if (_sqlServerConventionSet == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_sqlServerConventionSet == null)
                {
                    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                        .AddSqlServer<DbContext>("no-connection")
                        .BuildServiceProvider();
                    var context = serviceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
                    var conventionSetBuilder = context.GetInfrastructure()
                        .GetRequiredService<IProviderConventionSetBuilder>();
                    _sqlServerConventionSet = conventionSetBuilder.CreateConventionSet();
                }
            }
        }

        return _sqlServerConventionSet;
    }
}

Multi-Tenancy Configuration Extension
public static class MultiTenancyDbContextOptionsExtensions
{
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseSqlServerMultiTenant(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, string connectionString, string? schemaName, Func<string?, IModel> buildModel)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString, o => o.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(schemaName) ? schemaName : null))
            .UseModel(buildModel(schemaName))
            .ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, MultitenancySqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator>();

        // Ignore pending model changes warning
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schemaName))
            optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(RelationalEventId.PendingModelChangesWarning));

        return optionsBuilder;
    }
}

Overriding Migrations for Schema-Specific Operations
public class MultitenancySqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator(
    MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies,
    ICommandBatchPreparer commandBatchPreparer)
    : SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator(dependencies, commandBatchPreparer)
{

    public override IReadOnlyList<MigrationCommand> Generate(
        IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> operations,
        IModel? model = null,
        MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options = MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions.Default)
    {
        return base.Generate(RewriteOperations(operations, model, options), model, options);
    }

    private IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> RewriteOperations(
        IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations,
        IModel? model,
        MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
    {
        string? defaultSchema = null;

        bool IsDefaultSchema(string? schemaName)
        {
            return schemaName == null || schemaName == defaultSchema;
        }

        var schema = Dependencies.CurrentContext.Context.Model.GetDefaultSchema();

        if (schema == null || schema == defaultSchema)
            return migrationOperations;

        foreach (var operation in migrationOperations)
        {
            switch (operation)
            {
                case CreateTableOperation createTableOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(createTableOperation.Schema))
                    {
                        createTableOperation.Schema = schema;

                        foreach (var ck in createTableOperation.CheckConstraints.Where(ck => IsDefaultSchema(ck.Schema)))
                        {
                            ck.Schema = schema;
                        }

                        foreach (var uk in createTableOperation.UniqueConstraints.Where(uk => IsDefaultSchema(uk.Schema)))
                        {
                            uk.Schema = schema;
                        }

                        foreach (var fk in createTableOperation.ForeignKeys)
                        {
                            if (IsDefaultSchema(fk.Schema))
                            {
                                fk.Schema = schema;
                                fk.PrincipalSchema = schema;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case TableOperation tableOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(tableOperation.Schema)) 
                        tableOperation.Schema = schema;
                    break;
                case DropTableOperation dropTableOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(dropTableOperation.Schema)) 
                        dropTableOperation.Schema = schema;
                    break;
                case RenameTableOperation renameTableOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(renameTableOperation.Schema)) 
                        renameTableOperation.Schema = schema;
                    break;
                case ColumnOperation columnOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(columnOperation.Schema)) 
                        columnOperation.Schema = schema;
                    break;
                case CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(createIndexOperation.Schema)) 
                        createIndexOperation.Schema = schema;
                    break;
                case DropIndexOperation dropIndexOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(dropIndexOperation.Schema))
                        dropIndexOperation.Schema = schema;
                    break;
                case EnsureSchemaOperation ensureSchemaOperation:
                    if (IsDefaultSchema(ensureSchemaOperation.Name)) 
                        ensureSchemaOperation.Name = schema;
                    break;
                default:
                    //TODO: Add more operations
                    break;
            }
        }

        return migrationOperations;
    }
}

Final Notes
Once everything is correctly set up, you can generate migrations for the default schema and reuse them for each tenant's schema dynamically. This approach ensures that each tenant has its own migration history table and isolated schema configuration.

I managed to adapt your suggestion to my API and it worked perfectly! #happiness. Thank you very much!
I just have one question: When I need to update a migration (e.g. Update-Database) is it possible to make it go through all the databases making the changes?

Don't think so, you have to execute Migrate by yourself. Also, don't forget to accept answer if it works for you.

OK. In any case, thank you very much!
