# Creating a New Migration with All Table Structure for new Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project that I am working on.  While I have been coding it I have created the database on the Local SQL lite on my machine.  Now, I need to put it into production and I cannot get the migrations to create anything that is not blank.

Here is my old connection String:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=helpdesk;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I changed it into this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=SQL50;Database=HelpDesk;Trusted_Connection=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have tried from this thread ([Reset Entity-Framework Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations)):

1. Delete the migrations folder in your project
2. Delete the __MigrationHistory table in your database (may be under system tables) - However this one doesn't make sense because this is a new database and therefore has no migrations yet.

Whenever I try to create a new migration this is what I get:

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

I found this link about Initializers as suggested by Steve Greene Below (http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm)

and it suggests using this line of code:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogContext>());
```

In the main method.  However, I do not have a main method or any method similar to that at all.

Comment: What do you have your initializer set to?

Comment: @SteveGreene sorry but what is the initializer?

Comment: It determines if and when EF creates a new database. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @SteveGreene I added some more information to my original question.

Comment: Yeah, put that in the constructor of your context. static AppContext() { Database.SetInitializer(...);}

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is what I do if I want to start from scratch.

- Drop the local DB. - you can take a backup etc
- Delete the migrations folder from my project.(Check in to source
  control any model changes, this can sometimes cause issues).
- Run the Enable-Migrations command for my project. (this should add
  the migrations folder).
- Run the Add-Migration Initial. (this should
  the scaffold the db init).
- Run the Update-Database command (or run your application that uses
  the DBContext).