# How to replace all Migrations created by Code First with a new one

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have created a lot of migrations while I was developing my domain model. I would like to delete all of them and replace with a new one that will consist final form of my domain model.
Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset Entity-Framework Migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations)

Comment: I am not able to find __MigrationHistory table in my database. If I find it, I would like to delete only migrations that related to my last added domain model, not for all.

Comment: @ruud - You can't create multiple migrations without applying them, so you should have a __MigrationHistory table. In your question you say you want to delete them all, but in your comment you say you only want to remove the ones related to the "last added domain model". Need to clarify that. Here is a link on how to roll up a bunch of migrations into a single migration: http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible! You can manually delete the migration class files in the right side of Visual Studio.

Go to the console manager and type

```
Add-Migration NewestMigration //You can name it whatever you want by the way.
```