# ASP.NET - Unexpected column appears during Code First database update

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

So I've run into weird situation today - while updating existing database with new tables I got extra column in one of my tables.

How it looked like:

- Raport.cs

  ```
  public class Raport
  {
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
      [Key]
      public string raport_id { get; set; } //id raportu
      public string userID { get; set; }
      public DateTime creation_time { get; set; }
      public DateTime last_modyfication { get; set; }


      public virtual ICollection<ThrashType> ThrashType { get; set; }

      public virtual UserFrontInfo UserFrontInfo { get; set; }
  ```

  }
- ThrashType.cs

  ```
   public class ThrashType
     {     
      [Key] 
      //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
      public int IdTrash { get; set; }
      public string RaportId { get; set; } 
      public string ClassName { get; set; } 

      public int Quantity { get; set; }            
      public string Information { get; set; } 

      public virtual Raport Raport { get; set; }   

  }
  ```
- UserFrontInfo.cs

  ```
  public class UserFrontInfo
  {

      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
      [Key]
      public string userId { get; set; } 
      public string userName { get; set; } 
      public string whereFromName { get; set; } 

      public virtual ICollection<Raport> Raport { get; set; }  
  }
  ```

What I did before running into this situation:
1/added migrations
2/since I needed to append new tables I followed this: 
[Reset Entity-Framework Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations)
(1st comment under answers; more readable version) :

credits to Greg Gum for this (https://stackoverflow.com/users/425823/greg-gum)

> The Issue: You have mucked up your migrations and you would like to
>   reset it without deleting your existing tables. The Problem: You can't
>   reset migrations with existing tables in the database as EF wants to
>   create the tables from scratch. What to do: Delete existing migrations
>   from Migrations_History table. Delete existing migrations from the
>   Migrations Folder. Run add-migration Reset. This will create a
>   migration in your Migration folder that includes creating the tables
>   (but it will not run it so it will not error out.)  You now need to
>   create the initial row in the MigrationHistory table so EF has a
>   snapshot of the current state. EF will do this if you apply a
>   migration. However, you can't apply the migration that you just made
>   as the tables already exist in your database. So go into the Migration
>   and comment out all the code inside the "Up" method. Now run
>   update-database. It will apply the Migration (while not actually
>   changing the database) and create a snapshot row in MigrationHistory.
>   You have now reset your migrations and may continue with normal
>   migrations.

Then it all worked perfectly, but in ThrashType table I've got additional column named "Raport_raport_id".

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to change field name in ThrashType from "RaportId" to "raport_id", delete dbo.ThrashType and recreate the steps from above.

I'd like to point out that I've added one thing to the steps from above - in "number_digits_migration_file".cs I commented out only existing tables and left out those I wanted to create to.

Although I solved my problem I'm curious about it. Does anyone has had such experiance with Code First approach?

Have a great day!