# EF CF Migrate Existing Database without Package Manager

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

Assume that I have some database at my development PC. I then published my Asp.net App to some client. I took database backup and restored at client side.

After that, I have made some changes on schema of my local database. Those changes are added using Code-First migrations (using package-manager *Add-Migration*). Now I want to execute these migrations on client database. How do I do that?

For now, I receive this error when I run my new app on client side:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Comment: Consider starting migrations from a clean state http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-script` option of `update-database` (in the package manager console).

Rather than applying changes to you development database it will generate a script in a new editor tab.

Use the `-SourceMigration` and `-TargetMigration` option to define the set of migrations to include in the script (the first migration after the source up to and include the target migration will be included).