# Missing table from Code First EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I've developed a code first application that I've been having a lot of problems with. I have a class defined that mapped out the table 'PatientChart'
it looks like it:

```
public class PatientChart
{
    [Key]
    public int PatientChartId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2048)]
    public string Allergies { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2048)]
    public string PrimaryAilments { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2048)]
    public string Sensitivities { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2048)]
    public string Medications { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string ReferredBy { get; set; }
    public string ChartNotes { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2048)]
    public string MedicalHistory { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2048)]
    public string SocialHistory { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string PatientInfo_Id1 { get; set; }
    public virtual AspNetUser PatientInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I was having a lot of difficulty mapping a ForeignKey column (PatientInfo_Id). For some reason EntityFramework kept on mapping it to strange things like PatientInfo_Id1, Id2 ect. So I stupidly deleted the entire table from Sql Management Studio.

For the life of me I cannot get update-database to re-generate the table PatientChart. I've also cleared out that __MigrationHistory table! Poor decisions through and through.

Should I just delete the entire database and start over again?

Here is my DbContext:

```
public partial class HMSModel : DbContext
    {
        public HMSModel()
            : base("name=HMSModel")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRole> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ActiveSession> ActiveSessions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PatientChart> PatientCharts { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PatientCert> PatientCert { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PatientImages> PatientImages { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUserClaims)
                .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUserLogins)
                .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUserRoles)
                .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);



        }
    }
```

I've tried:
[Reset Entity-Framework Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations)
[Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table)
plus a million other links with no luck. I'm hoping someone clever here can help me.

That Chart class is supposed to be tied 1:1 to AspNetUser

```
 public partial class AspNetUser
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AspNetUser()
        {
            AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaim>();
            AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogin>();
            AspNetUserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserRole>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }

        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); } }

        public string DOB { get; set; }

        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [StringLength(2)]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [StringLength(25)]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [StringLength(25)]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool? ReceiveSMS { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public bool? Active { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRole> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUserRole AspNetUserRole { get; set; }
        public virtual PatientCert PatientCert { get; set; }
        //public virtual PatientChart PatientChart { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PatientImages> PatientImages { get; set; }

       // public virtual PatientChart PatientChart { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    }
```

I always use Database first for most large applications and this time I went Code First. I feel like Code First is a pain and riddled with problems but perhaps it's just my lack of depth of knowledge.

You can see the table is missing here
[[image: You can see the table is missing here[1]]

Comment: You aren't alone... So many code-first, and especially issues with code first & EF Core. I never saw how code first was ever practical beyond whipping up a very basic and disposable prototype. Too much of it seems like trial & error or worse, ends up in far from optimal schema definitions. That rumbling you hear is every deceased DBA rolling in their grave. :)

Comment: On topic, a couple of things stand out. You have several mappings defined for ASPNetuser for related items. I'd probably suggest moving these to an actual EntityTypeConfiguration<AspNetUser> instance which can hold the PK key mapping and relations for child collections. I'd also recommend using a meaningless key (I.e. sequence Int) for the PK on this table and related FKs and set up the current "Id" as a uniquely constrained indexed value.