# EF-Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We have MVC project with EF approach.
We got this error when we going to add migration

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass76_1.<FindRenamedIndexes>b__5(String c) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual[TSource](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass76_0.<FindRenamedIndexes>b__3(<>f__AnonymousType40`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier1)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
> at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion) at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
> at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInternal(String name, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String migrationsConfigurationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.Scaffold.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.b__0()
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> Sequence contains more than one element

** we change some key names for some models, I didn't know if it is relevant or not

and we didn't find any solutions work with EF approach,
so what's the possible solutions for this error ?

Comment: Did you refresh the mapping between the database tables and the c# classes after  making updates?  Looks like he model was changed and doesn't match the database.

Comment: Try to apply a migration with the new names for the keys (make sure EF knows they are the keys for that table). Should fix the problem.

Comment: - @jdweng to be honest with you I'm a beginner and I don't know anything about mapping, I'll search about it

Comment: - @NolanBradshaw I'm trying to add migration but it doesn't added because this error.

Comment: Ah, my mistake misread the question. You may need to reset your migrations to a fresh state as they may have gotten out of sync. Can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679385/reset-entity-framework-migrations