# How to completly remove migrations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

For some reason my project keeps generating a `__migrationhistory` table and I'm trying to get rid of that.

We used Migrations, but we want to remove them now. I already removed the Migration directory along with all migrations and configurations. I also dropped the whole schema and let it recreate using an `Initializer`.

I have no idea why this `__migrationhistory` is still created, I don't find anything related to Migrations in the project anymore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654055/how-can-i-disable-code-first-migrations

Comment: I have a custom DropCreateDatabaseAlways Initializer because I need to seed, but other than that I'm already doing what's suggested there. And that's not working unfortunately.