# How do I disable Code First Migrations in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I manually changed the database and the models to match, but I'm getting this error. How do I change ASP.NET Identity to not try to run database migrations?

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The model backing the
>   'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was
>   created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).]
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +262
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e()
>   +165    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +110
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +660    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext
>   c) +31
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>   +143    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +292
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   +123    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +42    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +39
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)
>   +41    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +142
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source,
>   String path) +205
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source,
>   Expression`1 path) +305
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1
>   filter) +610
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) +1071
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) +177
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__4.MoveNext() +803
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +21    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext() +468    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +24    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +123    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext() +795
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +24    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +123    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__d.MoveNext() +970
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93

Comment: the model shouldn't use that interface anymore CreateDatabaseIfNotExists - do you have an initializer using this? maybe in global?

Comment: Or maybe this is the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654055/how-can-i-disable-code-first-migrations

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yep, that's the answer. But I'm marking it as a duplicate of another question that is a little more clear.