# EF Core without migrations for existing SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Evening.

I have to develop an api for an existing SQL Server 2017 database.

I need to use Microsoft Web API, and I would like to use Core 3.1 but I have read I have to use migrations and such, and i have been told not to build the api using migrations.

Would I be better using .Net Framework instead or is there a way to use Core without using migrations?

I hope that it's not too broad a question, but I really am struggling to make a decision so any feedback etc would be greatly appreciated.

carlson

Comment: Web API is a web stack, not a data access technology or ORM. It doesn't perform migrations. You should be asking about *Entity Framework*, which has migrations both in .NET Old and .NET Core\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable code first migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654055/how-can-i-disable-code-first-migrations)

Comment: Why are you asking though? EF Core [doesn't execute migrations automatically](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3152) so you shouldn't have to do anything - just ensure you *don't* call `context.Database.Migrate()`. You need to do something to disable migrations only in .NET Old

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to access data from an existing database and tables with Entity Framework (EF) Core in your ASP.NET Core Web API project, you can try to use [Scaffold-DbContext command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) or [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) to generate code for a DbContext and entity types for your database.

[image]

Besides, you can also install and use [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) to access your existing SQL Server database in ASP.NET Core project.

Comment: The OP is asking how to *not* use migrations

Comment: `It doesn't perform migrations.` Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, as you mentioned, it does not require migration. About op's scenario "develop an api for an existing SQL Server 2017 database" I share how to access an existing db in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: One question is, if I don't use migration, how to ensure the code is in sync with database model updates apart from the obvious like adding a column.