# Painless use of View in Entity Framework 4

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm creating a webform vb.net project in visual studio 2012.
I am also using Entity Framework for managing my objects.
The big pain is caused by a View in my database, which I am forced to use.

I can retrieve the objects from this view with this class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Public Class C
    <Key, StringLength(6), Display(name:="C")> _
    Public Property IDC() As String
    <Display(Name:="Descrizione"), StringLength(255)> _
    Public Property Descrizione() As String
End Class
```

Now I would like to create a brand new model called "S". Every object of type S should refer to a object, of type C, therefore my code is:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Public Class S
    <Key, Display(name:="Id")> _
    Public Property SID() As Integer
    <Required, StringLength(255)>
    Public Property Descrizione() As String
    Public Overridable Property Commessa() As Commessa
End Class
```

Unfortunately, when I try to apply the migration, the process fails because tries to modify the View to enforce a contraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[S] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Ss_dbo.cs_C_IDC] FOREIGN KEY ([C_IDC]) REFERENCES [dbo].[c] ([IDC])
```

The migration code is:

```
    Public Overrides Sub Up()
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Ss",
            Function(c) New With
                {
                    .SID = c.Int(nullable := False, identity := True),
                    .Descrizione = c.String(nullable := False, maxLength := 255),
                    .C_IDC = c.String(maxLength := 6)
                }) _
            .PrimaryKey(Function(t) t.SID) _
            .ForeignKey("dbo.c", Function(t) t.C_IDC) _
            .Index(Function(t) t.C_IDC)
    End Sub
```

In the context class the correct View is defined:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of C)().ToTable("c")
End Sub
```

Googling this problem around, I "think" a possibility is to turn off the cascade delete feature, but even with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of S).HasRequired(Function(c) c.C).WithMany.WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
```

the migration tries to modify the View. (Is the code above correct?)

Is it possible to use the View in the Entity Framework in this way?
How can I link objects from the models I am going to create to elements in this View?

Is Entity Framework a reasonable approach in this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code First Migrations is designed to automatically manage your database.  If your DB has restrictions that make complete automation impossible (like Views), you could :

1. [Disable Code First Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709407/794234)
2. Let EF [generate a db update script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654094/794234) for you, but only apply the parts you want

There is some great general info on using Code First Migrations with an existing DB on [Ralph Lavelle's blog](http://www.ralphlavelle.net/2012/02/using-entity-framework-code-first-with_26.html).