# Entity Framework 5.0 and Migration/Edm metadata table - possible to get it to ignore them?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using EntityFramework 5.0 and I have a database that already exists but I want to define my own model for it so I do something like this:

```
pubilc class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Whatevers = Set<Whatever>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //.. Deal with all the mappings between the real database and
        // my beautiful model
    }

    pubilc DbSet<Whatever> Whatevers { get; private set;}
}

public class Whatever
{
   //... you get the gist...
}
```

It works fine except for the fact that the first time I start up the application it attempts to execute these two queries:

```
SELECT
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT TOP (1)
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
[Extent1].[ModelHash] AS [ModelHash]
FROM [dbo].[EdmMetadata] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC
```

Now, neither of those tables exist and therefore I get errors, and I really don't want them to (this is a database that has been around for a while and I am just a lowly application developer not a database overlord).

I saw this question: [How to disable migration in Entity Framework 4.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703810/how-to-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-4-3-1) that suggested this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists());
```

But [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) that is the default, in version 5.0 at least, anyway.

I see in MSDN that there are also:

- DropCreateDatabaseAlways
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
- MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

But none of those sound like what I want.

Is there a "leave the database alone - it doesn't know about the entity framework and, quite honestly, doesn't care to know about it" [IDatabaseInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) implementation somewhere?

Is it possible to make one?

Or is there some other property I can tweak - I could not find the `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` property mentioned in the answers to the question anywhere.

Or, perhaps there is a crucial reason why I actually need to have those tables in the database?

Comment: Write Enable-Migrations in packet manager console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Or

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Sadly, if I do `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();` it tells me that it is obsolete (and makes no difference anyway) and doing `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);` makes no difference.

Comment: So I just tried the SetInitializer(null) thing using EF 6 and it worked!  So either it did not work in EF5 or I was being a chump (probably the second), sorry.

Comment: Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null); should be in constructor of context class.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case Reverse Engineer Code First is the way to go.

You will need [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)
Further explained here: [Code First to an Existing Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx)

As far as i know this implements no migration or what so ever.

Comment: Sadly, that generates the same code that I am already writing by hand and, therefore, the two queries are still executed.