# Is it possible EF dont create __migrationhistory table on my first run using code first approach

Tags: entity-framework

I was thinking to achieve this by using ignore LINQ method.. but didnt have any clue how to achieve it.

```
public class MyHistoryContext : HistoryContext 
{ 
    public MyHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema) 
        : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema) 
    { 
    } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    { 
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
        modelBuilder.Ignore<HistoryRow>();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the __MigrationsHistory table then don't enable-migrations until you need the database updated. [How can I disable migration in Entity Framework 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667172/how-can-i-disable-migration-in-entity-6-0/28092685#28092685)

If you are trying to Ignore tables from the model you can annotate them with NotMapped https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.notmappedattribute(VS.103).aspx