# Why is EF trying to regenerate my schema?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, code-first

I'm tinkering with EF code-first strategy, after many years of being a db-first guy, and I have to admit, I like it.  I made myself a little test database and I enjoy the way EF automagically generates the script to update my schema.

So having played around with a little console app, I'm now hooking up to an ASP.NET MVC UI.  But now things are going wrong.  Because I haven't made any changes to my schema, but the first time a try to run a db query set off by my UI, for some reason EF is trying to regenerate my schema; moreover, it's doing it wrong and failing because it's trying to modify a field that has dependencies.  I can see all this happening in my SQL Server Profiler.

This is extremely weird.  When I run queries from my old console app, everything works fine.  When I run them from my ASP.NET project, it tries to modify my schema.  I removed the possibility of UI interference by writing a query in `global.asax.cs` in `Application_Start`, and it still does the migration shtick.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
What could cause this?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667172/how-can-i-disable-migration-in-entity-6-0

Comment: check weather your referring to same EF version in your Console app and ASP.NET project .