# How to disable migration on Db schema mismatch in code-first approach?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my team we C# developer do not have schema modification access to Database directly. There is a separate team which adds/alter tables for us. When a new requirement comes which needs a DB schema change they add the column/table and give us the details so we update our model class.

Following is the DataContext

```
public class FamilyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public FamilyDataContext() : base("FamilyDataContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ResidentInformation> ResidentInformation { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Problem: I am getting an error while trying to save data in this table.

> The model backing the 'FamilyDataContext'
>   context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

What I want is, if there is a mismatch in Model definition in C# code and Db schema, give an error so that it can be fixed manually either by dev or by DBA; rather than trying to upgrade the Database automatically. I do not want any automatic migration.

Is there anyway to achieve this please?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667172/how-can-i-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-6-0?

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks, thats what I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the null initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

but that will not tell you your model is out of sync. To do that, you will need to make a custom initializer, then do a check like

```
if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
{
    // handle out of sync
}
```

Here is a walkthrough on custom initializers: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm

or a more concise example: https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/