# Run the migrations with specific model updates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I' m working on a ASP.Net MVC project using Visual Studio 2017 .I want added a property to one of my models After i the migrations and starting the application i m getting and error message "There is already an object named in the database" . as i found on the  internet this is occurred due to automatic migrations , how to change my migration command to avoid this .

```
dotnet ef migrations add GeoLocation -c ApplicationDb -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ApplicationDb
```

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667172/how-can-i-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-6-0

Answer (score 0):

I do use EF migrations but I'm still not a fan. I prefer to develop in both SQL Server and C# separately. You can work around issues in various ways

Open a Nu-Get Package manager console and enable migrations for your project

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName YourProject.Models.ApplicationDbContext -Force
```

You can migrate whatever you have in your migration folder as follows (I've just shown the initial one) with or without the ignore changes flag

```
add-migration Initial
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```

Finally, force through the changes

```
Update-Database -Force
```

I always copy the contents of the "Configuration" file because that can get overwritten when I don't want. It can also add duplicate data to the database if your are not careful when it runs on a migration - so you'll need to code around that.

If I'm really stuck, I simply delete all migrations, truncate the migrations table, then perform an initial migration again.