EF 6 and SQL Server synonyms
I have a strange issue with SQL Server synonyms and EF 6.
A SQL Server database is set up with tables containing various non-dbo schemas (i.e. AZFSTSA and FMS). I would like the ASP.NET MVC application to be agnostic of the schema name, so each table has a synonym using dbo. The application should therefore be able to access all tables via dbo.
For example: a table is actually named AZFSTSA.DataAudits and the corresponding synonym is:
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[DataAudits] FOR [AZFSTSA].[DataAudits]

There are several entity classes and a datacontext class.
For example:
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Application.Entity.Models
{
    [Table("dbo.DataAudits")]
    public partial class DataAudit
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public DateTime Completed { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Process { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        [StringLength(8000)]
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
}

and
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("name=DataContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DataAudit> DataAudit { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AGCYFL> AGCYFL { get; set; }
}

There is no EF migration code in the application. All entity classes contain the same table attribute referencing dbo.
When I run the application, the first instance of data access produces the following error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'CbAgencies' in the database.

CbAgencies happens to be the first class in the EF Entities folder.
I tried to change the table name so it differs from the synonym alias (new table name = Audits, synonym alias is dbo.DataAudits). However the same error occurred.
If I modify the Table attribute only in the first entity class (CbAgencies) to include the actual schema (instead of dbo), the application runs fine. However as I mentioned earlier, I do not want to include the actual schema in case the schema changes.
How can I set up my application such that I do not need to use the actual schema name?

"I would like the ASP.NET MVC application to be agnostic of the schema name" Then why use schemas in the first place..? If you want everything to be "like" it's on the dbo schema then actually put everything in the dbo schema. This smells like an XY Problem.

EF6 (old) automatically applies migrations if you don't suppress that actively.

Also, it's easy to tell EF in which schema a table resides. You don't need these synonyms.

also, you really should be using schema-qualified names because it's generally good for performance.

"in case the schema changes"???? Do you make a habit of moving tables from schema to schema?

@SeanLange It's not unheard-of to use schemas to segregate archived old-data formerly in dbo, e.g. old2023.SalesData and old2022.SalesData, etc. It's slightly less worse than having year-named tables - and means you can re-run non-schema-qualified queries.

True, but one would assume that they aren't querying the old data, @Dai , and this the non-archived data. And, even then, the schema isn't going to change for old2023.SalesData, there will just be a new old2024 schema in the future. Of course, it's still an antipattern design.

@Dai there are lots of things that people do that are far less than ideal. That doesn't mean it is a good idea.

I agree with the comments and have voiced them many times. Unfortunately,  the procedures involving database maintenance  are far from ideal. The IT staff has been accustomed to changing schemas for over 20 years and are resistant to change. I am just trying to provide a workaround.

You still need to remap your synonym if schema is changed. But as others said, why not just not provide any schema at all, just the name. SQL Server can still resolve your object (me thinks)

This question remains: did you prevent automatic migrations from running?

I added a static constructor to disable auto migrations per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667172/how-can-i-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-6-0
That solution was successful. Thank you Gert Arnold!!!

OK, great! Just to bring this question to a closure I closed it as duplicate of the question you referred to.
