# Entity framework6 code first, how to disable schema verification

Tags: entity-framework-6, schema, code-first, verification

When i run my app, and try to load new DbContex, i see unacceptable long time to load the Form, i haven't change any thing in the schema, i think among the causes in this anomaly, the schema verification!
is it possible to disable this and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't validate the schema then you can't use migrations (essentially the verification is to see which migrations need to be applied).

To completely disable migrations see [How to disable migration in Entity Framework 4.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703810/how-to-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-4-3-1/9709407#9709407)